# Is it possible to run terminal/command prompt inside Rubymine?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I would work much faster if I could have some kind of command line running inside rubymine, is this possible? When testing I repeatedly have to switch to my terminal window and it gets quite annoying.

I can run rails console and also the sandboxed version side rubymine aswell as my rails server and spork server.

It would be nice to have a command prompt inside rubymine also would speed things up. Infact that would make rubymine 100% perfect for my rails development as it does everything else require.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no such feature in IDEA platform based products. You need to run terminal externally.  Note that you can create an `External Tool` to run terminal window in the current file or module directory for convenience.

**UPDATE**: Terminal (SSH console) was added in PhpStorm/WebStorm 7.0, IDEA 13, RubyMine 6, PyCharm 2.7.3.

Comment: I've heard something about doing that but not quite sure how to.

Comment: Please refer to the External Tools help section: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/external-tools.html.

Comment: phpStorm EAP Release has a terminal tool window !!! it is an idea platform product from jet brains...

Answer (score 10):

I have used CrazyCoder's instructions to do this. Here are the instructions for Windows:

- File, Settings
- bottom half of menu is titled IDE Settings, look in this list to find External Tools
- Click in the only available button (for most), [+]
- give your custom thing a name ("terminal"? "command prompt"?)

  - most of this stuff you just leave blank
  - click the [...] button next to Program, then simply navigate to Windows/system32/cmd.exe
  - Lastly, unless you want to have your starting command line (terminal) path as C:\Windows\system32 (CHANGE YOUR PATH), simply click on the [...] next to the "Working Directory" just below, and change your path to Desktop or whatever it is you prefer.
- Click OK.

You're done! It's that easy. Now to access this (no restart required), click on Tools, and then under 'XML actions' (for me anyway) you should find your "terminal" or "cmd" or whatever it is you called it. You can test it out with an 'ipconfig' command. You can always go back to the the settings/external-tools place you went to in the first place to edit your settings (like your default path), or to make another custom tool, because this (RubyMine External Tools creator) is obviously a very powerful tool.

Comment: Great answer. I followed your steps and created the external tool successfully. But it looks like the cmd in Rubymine has some problem with path. e.g. when I run "git init", it errors "'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." It works fine if I run it in native cmd.

Answer (score 5):

If someone is searching this for rubymine in version 7. 
Press **Alt+f12** for the terminal.

Source : https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html